# python: can't open file '/home/administrator/alphafold/run_alphafold.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to run docker for alphafold but it says that there is no '/home/administrator/alphafold/run_alphafold.py' in the directory even if it does exist

**Code I'm trying to run**

```
python3 alphafold/docker/run_docker.py \
--fasta_paths=your_protein.fasta \
--max_template_date=2022-01-01 \
--data_dir=/data8/Alphafold_database\
--output_dir=/data8/Alphafold_output_dir
```

OBS: this is just a test to know if docker is working (your_protein.fasta doesn't really exist)

**What it returns**

```
I0525 20:56:32.069198 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/fasta_path_0
I0525 20:56:32.069264 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/uniref90_database_path
I0525 20:56:32.069294 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/mgnify_database_path
I0525 20:56:32.069319 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/data_dir
I0525 20:56:32.069343 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/template_mmcif_dir
I0525 20:56:32.069365 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/obsolete_pdbs_path
I0525 20:56:32.069388 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/pdb70_database_path
I0525 20:56:32.069410 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/uniref30_database_path
I0525 20:56:32.069432 140690356790336 run_docker.py:116] Mounting /data8/Alphafold_output_dir -> /mnt/bfd_database_path
I0525 20:56:32.378198 140690356790336 run_docker.py:258] python: can't open file '/home/administrator/alphafold/run_alphafold.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**run_alphafold.py exists**

```
(base) administrator@LPgru:~$ cd /home/administrator/alphafold/
(base) administrator@LPgru:~/alphafold$ ls
afdb  alphafold  CONTRIBUTING.md  database  docs  imgs  LICENSE  notebooks  README.md  requirements.txt  run_alphafold.py  run_alphafold_test.py  scripts  setup.py
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    # Copyright 2021 DeepMind Technologies Limited
    #
    # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    # You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.
    
    ARG CUDA=11.1.1
    FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA}-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu18.04
    # FROM directive resets ARGS, so we specify again (the value is retained if
    # previously set).
    ARG CUDA
    
    # Use bash to support string substitution.
    SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
    
    RUN apt-get update \
        && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
            build-essential \
            cmake \
            cuda-command-line-tools-$(cut -f1,2 -d- <<< ${CUDA//./-}) \
            git \
            hmmer \
            kalign \
            tzdata \
            wget \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        && apt-get autoremove -y \
        && apt-get clean
    
    # Compile HHsuite from source.
    RUN git clone --branch v3.3.0 https://github.com/soedinglab/hh-suite.git /tmp/hh-suite \
        && mkdir /tmp/hh-suite/build \
        && pushd /tmp/hh-suite/build \
        && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/hhsuite .. \
        && make -j 4 && make install \
        && ln -s /opt/hhsuite/bin/* /usr/bin \
        && popd \
        && rm -rf /tmp/hh-suite
    
    # Install Miniconda package manager.
    RUN wget -q -P /tmp \
      https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
        && bash /tmp/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/conda \
        && rm /tmp/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    
    # Install conda packages.
    ENV PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"
    RUN conda install -qy conda==4.13.0 \
        && conda install -y -c conda-forge \
          openmm=7.7.0 \
          cudatoolkit==${CUDA_VERSION} \
          pdbfixer \
          pip \
          python=3.8 \
          && conda clean --all --force-pkgs-dirs --yes
    
    COPY . /home/administrator/alphafold
    RUN wget -q -P /home/administrator/alphafold/alphafold/common \
      https://git.scicore.unibas.ch/schwede/openstructure/-/raw/7102c63615b64735c4941278d92b554ec94415f8/modules/mol/alg/src/stereo_chemical_props.txt
    
    # Install pip packages.
    RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir \
        && pip3 install -r /home/administrator/alphafold/docker/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir \
        && pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir \
          jax==0.3.25 \
          jaxlib==0.3.25+cuda11.cudnn805 \
          -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
    
    # Add SETUID bit to the ldconfig binary so that non-root users can run it.
    RUN chmod u+s /sbin/ldconfig.real
    
    # We need to run `ldconfig` first to ensure GPUs are visible, due to some quirk
    # with Debian. See https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1399 for
    # details.
    # ENTRYPOINT does not support easily running multiple commands, so instead we
    # write a shell script to wrap them up.
    WORKDIR /home/administrator/alphafold
    RUN echo $'#!/bin/bash\n\
    ldconfig\n\
    python /home/administrator/alphafold/run_alphafold.py "$@"' > /home/administrator/run_alphafold.sh \
      && chmod +x /home/administrator/run_alphafold.sh
    ENTRYPOINT ["/home/administrator/run_alphafold.sh"]
```

**How Docker image was created**

```
(base) administrator@LPgru:~$ docker build -f alphafold/docker/Dockerfile -t alphafold .
```

~ means that is running from /home/administrator/

**run_docker.py**

```
    # Copyright 2021 DeepMind Technologies Limited
    #
    # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    # You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.
    
    """Docker launch script for Alphafold docker image."""
    
    import os
    import pathlib
    import signal
    from typing import Tuple
    
    from absl import app
    from absl import flags
    from absl import logging
    import docker
    from docker import types
    
    
    flags.DEFINE_bool(
        'use_gpu', True, 'Enable NVIDIA runtime to run with GPUs.')
    flags.DEFINE_enum('models_to_relax', 'best', ['best', 'all', 'none'],
                      'The models to run the final relaxation step on. '
                      'If `all`, all models are relaxed, which may be time '
                      'consuming. If `best`, only the most confident model is '
                      'relaxed. If `none`, relaxation is not run. Turning off '
                      'relaxation might result in predictions with '
                      'distracting stereochemical violations but might help '
                      'in case you are having issues with the relaxation '
                      'stage.')
    flags.DEFINE_bool(
        'enable_gpu_relax', True, 'Run relax on GPU if GPU is enabled.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'gpu_devices', 'all',
        'Comma separated list of devices to pass to NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.')
    flags.DEFINE_list(
        'fasta_paths', None, 'Paths to FASTA files, each containing a prediction '
        'target that will be folded one after another. If a FASTA file contains '
        'multiple sequences, then it will be folded as a multimer. Paths should be '
        'separated by commas. All FASTA paths must have a unique basename as the '
        'basename is used to name the output directories for each prediction.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'output_dir', '/tmp/alphafold',
        'Path to a directory that will store the results.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'data_dir', None,
        'Path to directory with supporting data: AlphaFold parameters and genetic '
        'and template databases. Set to the target of download_all_databases.sh.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'docker_image_name', 'alphafold', 'Name of the AlphaFold Docker image.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'max_template_date', None,
        'Maximum template release date to consider (ISO-8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD). '
        'Important if folding historical test sets.')
    flags.DEFINE_enum(
        'db_preset', 'full_dbs', ['full_dbs', 'reduced_dbs'],
        'Choose preset MSA database configuration - smaller genetic database '
        'config (reduced_dbs) or full genetic database config (full_dbs)')
    flags.DEFINE_enum(
        'model_preset', 'monomer',
        ['monomer', 'monomer_casp14', 'monomer_ptm', 'multimer'],
        'Choose preset model configuration - the monomer model, the monomer model '
        'with extra ensembling, monomer model with pTM head, or multimer model')
    flags.DEFINE_integer('num_multimer_predictions_per_model', 5, 'How many '
                         'predictions (each with a different random seed) will be '
                         'generated per model. E.g. if this is 2 and there are 5 '
                         'models then there will be 10 predictions per input. '
                         'Note: this FLAG only applies if model_preset=multimer')
    flags.DEFINE_boolean(
        'benchmark', False,
        'Run multiple JAX model evaluations to obtain a timing that excludes the '
        'compilation time, which should be more indicative of the time required '
        'for inferencing many proteins.')
    flags.DEFINE_boolean(
        'use_precomputed_msas', False,
        'Whether to read MSAs that have been written to disk instead of running '
        'the MSA tools. The MSA files are looked up in the output directory, so it '
        'must stay the same between multiple runs that are to reuse the MSAs. '
        'WARNING: This will not check if the sequence, database or configuration '
        'have changed.')
    flags.DEFINE_string(
        'docker_user', f'{os.geteuid()}:{os.getegid()}',
        'UID:GID with which to run the Docker container. The output directories '
        'will be owned by this user:group. By default, this is the current user. '
        'Valid options are: uid or uid:gid, non-numeric values are not recognised '
        'by Docker unless that user has been created within the container.')
    
    FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
    
    _ROOT_MOUNT_DIRECTORY = '/mnt/'
    
    
    def _create_mount(mount_name: str, path: str) -> Tuple[types.Mount, str]:
      """Create a mount point for each file and directory used by the model."""
      path = pathlib.Path('/data8/Alphafold_output_dir').absolute()
      target_path = pathlib.Path(_ROOT_MOUNT_DIRECTORY, mount_name)
    
      if path.is_dir():
        source_path = path
        mounted_path = target_path
      else:
        source_path = path.parent
        mounted_path = pathlib.Path(target_path, path.name)
      if not source_path.exists():
        raise ValueError(f'Failed to find source directory "{source_path}" to '
                         'mount in Docker container.')
      logging.info('Mounting %s -> %s', source_path, target_path)
      mount = types.Mount(target=str(target_path), source=str(source_path),
                          type='bind', read_only=True)
      return mount, str(mounted_path)
    
    
    def main(argv):
      if len(argv) > 1:
        raise app.UsageError('Too many command-line arguments.')
    
      # You can individually override the following paths if you have placed the
      # data in locations other than the FLAGS.data_dir.
    
      # Path to the Uniref90 database for use by JackHMMER.
      uniref90_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'uniref90', 'uniref90.fasta')
    
      # Path to the Uniprot database for use by JackHMMER.
      uniprot_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'uniprot', 'uniprot.fasta')
    
      # Path to the MGnify database for use by JackHMMER.
      mgnify_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'mgnify', 'mgy_clusters_2022_05.fa')
    
      # Path to the BFD database for use by HHblits.
      bfd_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'bfd',
          'bfd_metaclust_clu_complete_id30_c90_final_seq.sorted_opt')
    
      # Path to the Small BFD database for use by JackHMMER.
      small_bfd_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'small_bfd', 'bfd-first_non_consensus_sequences.fasta')
    
      # Path to the Uniref30 database for use by HHblits.
      uniref30_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'uniref30', 'UniRef30_2021_03')
    
      # Path to the PDB70 database for use by HHsearch.
      pdb70_database_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'pdb70', 'pdb70')
    
      # Path to the PDB seqres database for use by hmmsearch.
      pdb_seqres_database_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.data_dir, 'pdb_seqres', 'pdb_seqres.txt')
    
      # Path to a directory with template mmCIF structures, each named <pdb_id>.cif.
      template_mmcif_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'pdb_mmcif', 'mmcif_files')
    
      # Path to a file mapping obsolete PDB IDs to their replacements.
      obsolete_pdbs_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'pdb_mmcif', 'obsolete.dat')
    
      alphafold_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
      data_dir_path = pathlib.Path(FLAGS.data_dir)
      if alphafold_path == data_dir_path or alphafold_path in data_dir_path.parents:
        raise app.UsageError(
            f'The download directory {FLAGS.data_dir} should not be a subdirectory '
            f'in the AlphaFold repository directory. If it is, the Docker build is '
            f'slow since the large databases are copied during the image creation.')
    
      mounts = []
      command_args = []
    
      # Mount each fasta path as a unique target directory.
      target_fasta_paths = []
      for i, fasta_path in enumerate(FLAGS.fasta_paths):
        mount, target_path = _create_mount(f'fasta_path_{i}', fasta_path)
        mounts.append(mount)
        target_fasta_paths.append(target_path)
      command_args.append(f'--fasta_paths={",".join(target_fasta_paths)}')
    
      database_paths = [
          ('uniref90_database_path', uniref90_database_path),
          ('mgnify_database_path', mgnify_database_path),
          ('data_dir', FLAGS.data_dir),
          ('template_mmcif_dir', template_mmcif_dir),
          ('obsolete_pdbs_path', obsolete_pdbs_path),
      ]
    
      if FLAGS.model_preset == 'multimer':
        database_paths.append(('uniprot_database_path', uniprot_database_path))
        database_paths.append(('pdb_seqres_database_path',
                               pdb_seqres_database_path))
      else:
        database_paths.append(('pdb70_database_path', pdb70_database_path))
    
      if FLAGS.db_preset == 'reduced_dbs':
        database_paths.append(('small_bfd_database_path', small_bfd_database_path))
      else:
        database_paths.extend([
            ('uniref30_database_path', uniref30_database_path),
            ('bfd_database_path', bfd_database_path),
        ])
      for name, path in database_paths:
        if path:
          mount, target_path = _create_mount(name, path)
          mounts.append(mount)
          command_args.append(f'--{name}={target_path}')
    
      output_target_path = os.path.join(_ROOT_MOUNT_DIRECTORY, 'output')
      mounts.append(types.Mount(output_target_path, FLAGS.output_dir, type='bind'))
    
      use_gpu_relax = FLAGS.enable_gpu_relax and FLAGS.use_gpu
    
      command_args.extend([
          f'--output_dir={output_target_path}',
          f'--max_template_date={FLAGS.max_template_date}',
          f'--db_preset={FLAGS.db_preset}',
          f'--model_preset={FLAGS.model_preset}',
          f'--benchmark={FLAGS.benchmark}',
          f'--use_precomputed_msas={FLAGS.use_precomputed_msas}',
          f'--num_multimer_predictions_per_model={FLAGS.num_multimer_predictions_per_model}',
          f'--models_to_relax={FLAGS.models_to_relax}',
          f'--use_gpu_relax={use_gpu_relax}',
          '--logtostderr',
      ])
    
      client = docker.from_env()
      device_requests = [
          docker.types.DeviceRequest(driver='nvidia', capabilities=[['gpu']])
      ] if FLAGS.use_gpu else None
    
      container = client.containers.run(
          image=FLAGS.docker_image_name,
          command=command_args,
          device_requests=device_requests,
          remove=True,
          detach=True,
          mounts=mounts,
          user=FLAGS.docker_user,
          environment={
              'NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES': FLAGS.gpu_devices,
              # The following flags allow us to make predictions on proteins that
              # would typically be too long to fit into GPU memory.
              'TF_FORCE_UNIFIED_MEMORY': '1',
              'XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION': '4.0',
          })
    
      # Add signal handler to ensure CTRL+C also stops the running container.
      signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,
                    lambda unused_sig, unused_frame: container.kill())
    
      for line in container.logs(stream=True):
        logging.info(line.strip().decode('utf-8'))
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      flags.mark_flags_as_required([
          'data_dir',
          'fasta_paths',
          'max_template_date',
      ])
      app.run(main)
```

Comment: Does the file exist inside the docker image? Your `ls` in `~/alphafold` appears to be run on your host machine, not inside the docker container. It's unclear to me whether the error message is generated inside or outside the docker image, to be honest...

Comment: how do I verify that

Comment: Share your Dockerfile, for an important starter, and maybe where you got this code.

Comment: If the command `run_alphafold` is invoked from a RUN or ENTRYPOINT command in the Dockerfile, it's being run from within.

Comment: I just added the Dockerfile in the body, and alphafold really is invoked from ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Is there any way to add the file to the docker image?

Comment: you can add files to Docker container yes. utilise command called docker cp.

Comment: How is the container being created; what is in the host's `run_docker.py`?  Can you demonstrate the same problem with a much smaller Dockerfile?

Comment: I found out what was happening. Inside the docker file changed "COPY . /home/administrator/alphafold" to "COPY /alphafold /home/administrator/alphafold"

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening. Inside the docker file I changed:

```
"COPY . /home/administrator/alphafold"
```

To:

```
"COPY /alphafold /home/administrator/alphafold"
```

After that the error was not happening anymore